# Does it take a larger force to stop a faster object?

Tags: forces, mass, acceleration

Does it take a larger force to stop a car that is moving at a velocity **2*v** than if it is moving at a velocity **v**? I'm confused as the force required to decelerate a car depends on the mass and the deceleration that needs to be done and assuming we want to decelerate at the same rate we accelerated before, this force doesn't depend on the velocity of the car.

Comment: It depends on the momentum and not the mass(only).

Comment: But the force doesn't depend on momentum. Does that mean the force is the same?

Comment: You might be knowing F=dp/dt?

Comment: The term p depends on both mass and the velocity

Comment: Adding to the above, Newton's second law leads to the impulse-momentum theorem: $\int_{t_a}^{t_b}Fdt = p(t_b) - p(t_a)$. If the mass of the object is constant, this becomes $\int_{t_a}^{t_b}Fdt = m\left(v(t_b) - v(t_a)\right)$. In other words, assuming the mass of the object is constant, you can stop it by applying a small force over a long time, a large force over a short time, or even a varying force. However, if you seek the same rate of acceleration for two objects, the force required is indeed proportional to the mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantity *force* times *time* is called [impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics)), and it is equal to change of momentum.

The car starts with a momentum $mv$ and ends up with momentum zero, so the change in momentum is $mv$. If you use a constant force $F$ for a time $t$ to stop the car this means:

$$ Ft = mv $$

or:

$$ F = \frac{mv}{t} $$

If you change the car velocity to $2v$ and you want to stop the car in the same time, then the new force is:

$$ F_2 = \frac{2mv}{t} $$

which is twice as great as the original force. So in this sense it does take a large force to stop the faster car. But if you don't mind the car taking a long time to stop you could use a lower force for a longer time.

Answer (score 0):

We need a larger force if the momentum is high or time which is spent to zero the momentum is short.